# volumes_from (from version 2) equivalent for docker-compose version 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been following a blog for setting up Nginx with SSL from https://blog.harveydelaney.com/hosting-websites-using-docker-nginx/

The article refers to a `docker-compose.yml` file that doesn't have a version specified at the beginning, but I assume it's at least version 2 as it does have a reference to `volumes_from` setting within it. This `volumes_from` is no longer supported in version 3.

Could someone please help migrate the following file to version 3? I am new to the docker / docker-compose / K8s world.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    proxy:
      image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
      container_name: nginx-proxy
      ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
        - /usr/share/nginx/html
        - C:\Data\DockerData\nginxSSL\certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro

    ssl-companion:
      image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
      container_name: ssl-companion
      volumes:
        - C:\Data\DockerData\nginxSSL\certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      volumes_from: # <-- version 3 doesn't like this
        - proxy
      depends_on:
        - proxy
```

---

**Update after answer:** (for anyone looking to find answer in question)

- version 3 no longer supports `volumes_from`, per David's answer below there are two options:

  1. use compose version 2,
  2. or repeat each volume that needs to be same among services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Compose file version 3 upgrade nodes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#upgrading) say:

> `volumes_from`: To share a volume between services, define it using the [top-level `volumes` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) and reference it from each service that shares it using the [service-level `volumes` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver).

You have to do this for each directory you want to share.  For the nginx virtual hosts directory, for example:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  vhosts: # can be empty
services:
  proxy:
    volumes:
      - vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  ssl-companion:
    volumes:
      - vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
```

Using the `volumes_from:` option is a little unusual in general: it involves one container wanting to use *every* volume from another, and their filesystem layouts being compatible so that they can use the exact same paths.

(You mention Kubernetes in the question.  Sharing files between Kubernetes pods is tricky, since most of the standard volume types can only be mounted in one place at a time, and generally you should try to design around needing shared volumes [even in plain Docker].  In this specific case where the two processes are very closely connected you could create an `emptyDir` volume to share between two containers in a single pod, but in general that's an unusual setup.)

Comment: just to make sure I understood it correct, the `volumes_from` option is made redundant in version 3 and cannot be used. We must repeat / copy-paste each line from the service we wish get volumes from. Is that correct? (I agree, it would be unlikely that multiple services would require exact same set of volumes shared)

Comment: Yes.  Using Compose `version: '2'` is also a valid workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto David Maze's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230496/12488391), these are the relevant bits from a working `docker-compose.yml` file that follows the [letsencrypt-nginx-sidecar](https://github.com/jwulf/letsencrypt-nginx-sidecar) design pattern from the original question.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
      - "nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - "vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
      - "nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy
volumes:
  vhosts:
  nginx:
  certs:
```

**Note**: To complete the migration to docker-compose v3, the `NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER` environment variable needs to be set on the `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` container with the `container_name` value from `nginx-proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

`volumes_from` doesn't make sense in Swarm Mode since containers in Swarm Mode may be on different nodes, and therefore you cannot share bind mounts between those containers.

Why am I talking about Swarm Mode? Because that's the reason for compose version 3.x. Don't look at the version like a normal upgrade, it's the easiest way Docker had to specify what was supported in Swarm Mode, making 3.x a requirement to update the file to run in Swarm Mode. Though it's compatible to run a 3.x compose file in `docker-compose` too.

If you aren't using Swarm Mode, then stick with either version 2.x of the compose file, or upgrade to the [compose spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) which has no version number. You'll also want to switch from `docker-compose` the python command to `docker compose` (with a space) which is written in Go (in newer versions of docker, you may find `docker-compose` is a stub pointing to `docker compose`). The compose-spec is a combination of the version 2 and version 3 syntax and different implementations use the features they understand from this spec.

As others have mentioned, `volumes_from` is a relatively legacy feature. It was designed before named volumes were available in docker, and so sharing volumes between containers would involve creating a data container. If the data container was every deleted, so was your data, so workflows quickly moved away from that model (since containers are typically ephemeral).